# Wrong rendered name of child view model property

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   //...
   [UIHint("Children")
   public IList<ChildViewModdel> Children {get;set;}
}
```

where ChildViewModel class has Quantity property (of type long).

Here is Children editor template:

```
@model  IList<ChildViewModel>
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x[index])
}
```

Now I render the model by `@Html.EditorForModel()` and as result first ChildViewModel's Quanity text box name is `Children.[0].Quantity`. Do you see this extra point before [0]? As result model binder doesn't recognize these values and doesn't process them correctly when user posts the form. How can I make ASP.NET MVC rener `Children[0].Quantity` name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me state that this is kinda correct behavior (at least "by design"). When MVC dives into the nested properties it appends the "PropertyName." (mention the dot at the end) in front of every field inside that nested model. So you get "Children." from the `ViewModel`, "[0]." from the `IList<ChildViewModel>` and "Quantity" from the  `ChildViewModel`.

The main question here is why do you need a special template for `IList<ChildViewModel>`? MVC has its own special cases for handling IEnumerables, so normally you shouldn't interfere.

If you really need some special handling you could wrap `IList<ChildViewModel>` into another class and introduce your special logic in the EditorTemplate for that class. It'd be like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public ChildViewModdels Children {get;set;}
}
public class ChildViewModdels 
{
   public IList<ChildViewModdel> Children {get;set;}
}
```

And here it goes your special logic in the ChildViewModdels EditorTemplate

```
@model  ChildViewModdels
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Children.Count(); index++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Children[index])
}
```

Again, this is for the case if you **really need** that special logic (which is uncertain from the question)